# How to fix rust operations not working as expected?

Tags: rust

I have implemented a simple command-line calculator in Rust. The add function acts as normal but the subtract, multiply, and divide functions don't work. The rest of the code is on GitHub: https://github.com/henryboisdequin/rust-calculator.

`calc.rs`

```
impl Calc {
    pub fn add(arr: Vec<i64>) -> f64 {
        let mut total: f64 = 0.0;

        for num in arr {
            total += num as f64;
        }

        total
    }

    pub fn sub(arr: Vec<i64>) -> f64 {
        let mut total: f64 = 0.0;

        for num in arr {
            total -= num as f64;
        }

        total
    }

    pub fn mul(arr: Vec<i64>) -> f64 {
        let mut total: f64 = 0.0;

        for num in arr {
            total *= num as f64;
        }

        total
    }

    pub fn div(arr: Vec<i64>) -> f64 {
        let mut total: f64 = 0.0;

        for num in arr {
            total /= num as f64;
        }

        total
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Check the intermediate results and compare them to hand calculations you do on paper to verify that the loops are proceeding as expected. Or pass in 1- or 2-element vectors and see what results you get. It should be straightforward to fix all three once you do that.

Comment: I tried to do that but it keeps returning nonsense numbers.

Comment: At least two sub-problems of this are math problems. Your addition function only works because addition is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) and because your initial value of `0.0` happens to be the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) of addition. For all your other functions, at least one of these does not hold true. Or, in blunt terms: zero times x remains zero, and a minus b does not equal b minus a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having your functions take `Vec<i64>`, I would instead suggest `&[i64]`, or even `&[f64]` to avoid the `as f64`. This *wouldn't* really break your existing code, as you can just borrow a `Vec<i64>`, to have it auto dereference into `&[i64]`.

You can simplify `add()` by using [`sum()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum), and `mul()` by using [`product()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.product).

```rust
pub fn add(arr: &[i64]) -> f64 {
    arr.iter().map(|&x| x as f64).sum()
}

pub fn mul(arr: &[i64]) -> f64 {
    arr.iter().map(|&x| x as f64).product()
}
```

You can similarly simplify `sub()` and `div()` with [`next()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) and then [`fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold).

```rust
pub fn sub(arr: &[i64]) -> f64 {
    let mut it = arr.iter().map(|&x| x as f64);
    it.next()
        .map(|x| it.fold(x, |acc, x| acc - x))
        .unwrap_or(0.0)
}

pub fn div(arr: &[i64]) -> f64 {
    let mut it = arr.iter().map(|&x| x as f64);
    it.next()
        .map(|x| it.fold(x, |acc, x| acc / x))
        .unwrap_or(0.0)
}
```

You can even simplify them further, by using [`fold_first()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold_first). However that is currently experimental and nightly only. Instead you can use [`fold1()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.fold1) from the [`itertools` crate](https://crates.io/crates/itertools), or [`reduce()`](https://docs.rs/reduce/0.1.4/reduce/index.html) from the [`reduce` crate](https://crates.io/crates/reduce).

```rust
// itertools = "0.10"
use itertools::Itertools;

pub fn sub(arr: &[i64]) -> f64 {
    arr.iter().map(|&x| x as f64).fold1(|a, b| a - b).unwrap_or(0.0)
}

pub fn div(arr: &[i64]) -> f64 {
    arr.iter().map(|&x| x as f64).fold1(|a, b| a / b).unwrap_or(0.0)
}
```

You can even replace the closures with [`Sub::sub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Sub.html#tymethod.sub) and [`Div::div`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Div.html#tymethod.div).

```rust
// itertools = "0.10"
use itertools::Itertools;
use std::ops::{Div, Sub};

pub fn sub(arr: &[i64]) -> f64 {
    arr.iter().map(|&x| x as f64).fold1(Sub::sub).unwrap_or(0.0)
}

pub fn div(arr: &[i64]) -> f64 {
    arr.iter().map(|&x| x as f64).fold1(Div::div).unwrap_or(0.0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Siguza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302862/siguza) helped me fix this problem by specifying that my addition function only works because addition is commutative but the other operations are failing because they are not.

Here is the right code:

```rust
pub struct Calc;

impl Calc {
    pub fn add(arr: Vec<i64>) -> f64 {
        let mut total: f64 = 0.0;

        for num in arr {
            total += num as f64;
        }

        total
    }

    pub fn sub(arr: Vec<i64>) -> f64 {
        let mut total: f64 = arr[0] as f64;
        let mut counter = 0;

        while counter != arr.len() - 1 {
            total -= arr[counter + 1] as f64;
            counter += 1;
        }

        total
    }

    pub fn mul(arr: Vec<i64>) -> f64 {
        let mut total: f64 = arr[0] as f64;

        let mut counter = 0;

        while counter != arr.len() - 1 {
            total *= arr[counter + 1] as f64;
            counter += 1;
        }

        total
    }

    pub fn div(arr: Vec<i64>) -> f64 {
        let mut total: f64 = arr[0] as f64;

        let mut counter = 0;

        while counter != arr.len() - 1 {
            total /= arr[counter + 1] as f64;
            counter += 1;
        }

        total
    }
}
```

For the operations excluding 0, instead of assigning the total to `0.0`, I assigned the total to the first element of the given array and `-`/`*`/`/` the total with the rest of the elements in the array.

Comment: You can simplify `add` by using [`sum()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum), and `mul` by using [`product()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.product). You can similarly simplify `sub` and `div` with `next()` and then [`fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) :)

Comment: @vallentin Could you please show me show to implement the `sub` and `div` with `next()` and `fold()` please because I can't figure it out?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute :)